# Getting error while opening excel file in Python

Tags: qgis, python

I am very new to Python, here I'm trying to open an Excel XLS file in Python code but it is showing me some error as below.

Code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import os.path
wb = open_workbook('K:\NEW_GIS\NEW Data\Garpani_NLRMP_Data\ROR_Files\part-1.xlsx')
```

I am also following below link for upgrade version:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\Import_tool.py", line 327, in select_output_file_5
    workbook = open_workbook(r'K:\NEW_GIS\NEW Data\Garpani_NLRMP_Data\ROR_Files\Part-1.xlsx')

  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 429, in open_workbook
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)

  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1545, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])

  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1539, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found 'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00'
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\Import_tool.py", line 327, in select_output_file_5
    workbook = open_workbook(r'K:\NEW_GIS\NEW Data\Garpani_NLRMP_Data\ROR_Files\Part-1.xlsx')
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 429, in open_workbook
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)

Comment: please do not place information for the question in comments. Edit original question.

Answer (score 2):

Excel workbooks carry a considerable amount of formatting that can make them tough to deal with in python. I have found that it is easier to work with tabular data in python using the built-in csv module. In case you aren't familiar, CSV is a standard way to simplify reading & writing of a singular tabular data table.

To [export as a CSV](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) open the spreadsheet in Excel and choose 'Save as'. In the 'Save as type' drop-down choose 'CSV (Comma Delimited)'

Once your data is in the CSV format, use the built-in 'csv' module to read it contents.

```
import csv
csv_file_path = r"..\myData.csv"

with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        print row
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't escaped your backslashes. Try using a raw string by placing the letter 'r' in front of the string.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import os.path
wb = open_workbook(r'K:\NEW_GIS\NEW Data\Garpani_NLRMP_Data\ROR_Files\part-1.xlsx')
```

Comment: I am getting :Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\Import_tool.py", line 327, in select_output_file_5 workbook = open_workbook(r'K:\NEW_GIS\NEW Data\Garpani_NLRMP_Data\ROR_Files\Part-1.xlsx') File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd_init_.py", line 429, in open_workbook biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't leave out the last line of the error? What you pasted shows the traceback but I don't see an error message. Please edit the full error message **into your original question**

Comment: I have edited the full error message into my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Your spreadsheet is in Excel 2007+ .xlsx [OOXML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). The link in your question is to the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org) docs which can read .xlsx but you're not using openpyxl, you're trying to open the .xlsx file with [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) which only reads the old [Excel binary .xls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats) format.

Here is some [more information](http://www.python-excel.org/) on working with Excel spreadsheets in Python.